# warning occured when running pyscenic

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, distributed-computing, scenic

I am running PySCENIC using the protocols described in the paper titled "A scalable SCENIC workflow for single-cell gene regulatory network analysis". I have generated Loom files using the PBMC dataset downloaded from 10x Genomics, as suggested in the paper. However, when I input the following code:

```
(scenic_protocol) lij@shpc-1392-instance-hgaxepHO:~$ pyscenic grn --num_workers 20 --output adj.tsv --method grnboost2 PBMC10k_filtered.loom hs_hgnc_tfs.txt
```

an error occurred:

(here is the code and error demonstration:)

```
(scenic_protocol) lij@shpc-1392-instance-hgaxepHO:~$ pyscenic grn --num_workers 20 --output adj.tsv --method grnboost2 PBMC10k_filtered.loom hs_hgnc_tfs.txt

2023-06-05 10:02:26,215 - pyscenic.cli.pyscenic - INFO - Loading expression matrix.

2023-06-05 10:02:30,653 - pyscenic.cli.pyscenic - INFO - Inferring regulatory networks.
/home/lij/miniconda3/envs/scenic_protocol/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/node.py:182: UserWarning: Port 8787 is already in use.
Perhaps you already have a cluster running?
Hosting the HTTP server on port 39847 instead
warnings.warn(
preparing dask client
parsing input
creating dask graph
2023-06-05 10:09:22,886 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not find data: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:40481']} on workers: [] (who_has: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:40481']})
2023-06-05 10:09:25,385 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:34745 failed to acquire keys: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ('tcp://127.0.0.1:40481',)}
2023-06-05 10:09:48,372 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not find data: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:44933']} on workers: [] (who_has: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:44933']})
2023-06-05 10:09:50,752 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:41941 failed to acquire keys: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ('tcp://127.0.0.1:44933',)}
2023-06-05 10:11:22,756 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not find data: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:43283', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025']} on workers: [] (who_has: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:43283', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025']})
2023-06-05 10:11:22,763 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not find data: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:43283', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025']} on workers: [] (who_has: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:43283', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025']})
2023-06-05 10:11:25,204 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:35385 failed to acquire keys: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ('tcp://127.0.0.1:43283', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025')}
2023-06-05 10:11:25,204 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:41555 failed to acquire keys: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ('tcp://127.0.0.1:43283', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025')}
2023-06-05 10:11:57,216 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not find data: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:37661', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:41941', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:35717']} on workers: [] (who_has: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:37661', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:41941', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:35717']})
2023-06-05 10:11:57,274 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not find data: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:37661', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:41941', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:35717']} on workers: [] (who_has: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:37661', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:41941', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:35717']})
2023-06-05 10:11:59,471 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:37643 failed to acquire keys: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ('tcp://127.0.0.1:37661', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:41941', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:35717')}
2023-06-05 10:11:59,473 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:39775 failed to acquire keys: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ('tcp://127.0.0.1:37661', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:41941', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:35717')}
2023-06-05 10:13:01,197 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Could not find data: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:44933', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:40481', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:34745', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:39775', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025']} on workers: [] (who_has: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ['tcp://127.0.0.1:44933', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:40481', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:34745', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:39775', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025']})
2023-06-05 10:13:03,690 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:43555 failed to acquire keys: {'ndarray-bfe6126093e0117e52fb084d3f577fc9': ('tcp://127.0.0.1:44933', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:40481', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:34745', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:39775', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33025')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error before.
I do not know why, but it might be related to the port number; In my case, I solved the issue just by using Port 8787.

Hope it helps.